# Access sub-folders in kdb+/Q

Tags: kdb

The below script returns the list of files included in `Main_Dir` (which only includes folders)

```
path: `$":D:/Main_Dir/
files: key(path)
```

However, I would like to access the files (`.csvs`) which reside in the sub-folder for which the path being: `D:/Main_Dir/sub_dir1,D:/Main_Dir/sub_dir2...sub_dir3`

This code is a part of the larger sub-block, which intends to read csvs residing in the sub-folder.

```
path: `$":D:/Main_Dir/
files: key(path)
loadcsv: {[path;file]("SDNFFFFJJ";enlist csv) 0: ` sv path,file}
d2: raze loadcsv[path] each files
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of variety, a recursive approach which would work for arbitrarily nested directories (similar to how MurrMacks answer would):

```
q){$[{x~key x}y;(();y)y like x;raze .z.s[x]each` sv'y,'key y]}["*.csv";`:.]
`:./dir1/f1.csv`:./dir3/f3.csv`:./dir3/subdir1/f3s.csv`:./dir3/subdir1/subsubdir2/f3ss.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

I have made a small test directory

```
 λ tree
.
├── subdir1
│   └── hi.csv
├── subdir2
│   └── hi.csv
└── subdir3
    ├── hi.csv
    └── hi.txt

3 directories, 4 files
```

What you could do is make a list of all of the full (relative) paths of the files, and then filter out the ones that aren't csv using `like`.

```
q)paths: paths where (paths: raze {` sv' dir ,/: key dir: hsym x} each key `:.) like "*.csv"
`:subdir1/hi.csv`:subdir2/hi.csv`:subdir3/hi.csv
```

Then you could do your reading in of these files just using the each.

```
{[path] ("SDNFFFFJJ";enlist csv) 0: path} each paths
```

Would this work?

Comment: Tried using the solution as follows :

`paths: paths where (paths: raze {` 'sv path ,/: key path: hsym x} each key ':.) like "*.txt" `

gets me an output as :

` `symbol`

where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

To add to Matthews answer and to give a different approach - you could use a system command with the linux 'find' utility. Using the same directory structure -

```
q)hsym `$system"find . -type f -name '*.csv'"
 `:subdir1/hi.csv`:subdir2/hi.csv`:subdir3/hi.csv
```

Matthews answer is much better and I would avoid using system commands in a production system but in this case its a simpler solution.

++ edit -noticing you are on windows
you can use

```
q)hsym `$system"dir *.csv /b/s"
 `:subdir1/hi.csv`:subdir2/hi.csv`:subdir3/hi.csv
```